# AppEngine domain redirect using web.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to intercept all incoming requests e.g.

```
http://subdomain.domain.org/path/to/resource
```

to

```
https://appengineid.appspot.com/path/to/resource
```

for any possible /path/to/resource

Is this possible with the app engine web.xml deployment descriptor? 
When I search this topic all the documentation or questions/answers relate to transforming/translating the /path/to/resource part of a request rather than the subdomain.domain.tld part?

Thanks

QUESTION EDIT/UPDATE:

Both of the above URLs point to the exact same instance of an app engine application. I don't want to URL pattern match on the /path/to/resource because this would "match" requests to both URLs. I want to URL pattern match on the domain part of the URL, so that any requests to subdomain.domain.org are redirected to appengineid.appspot.com, and then, so that no cycle is encountered any requests to appengineid.appspot.com are ignored by the redirecting filter and are handled by the rest of the web deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that a Filter will solve your problem. 
You create a new filter in your web.xml, like this:

```
     <filter> 
         <filter-name>yourFilterName</filter-name>
         <filter-class>com.acme.filter.YourNewFilter</filter-class> 
     </filter> 
     <filter-mapping> 
         <filter-name>yourFilterName</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/path/to/resource/*</url-pattern> 
      </filter-mapping>
```

Your filter class will be something like this:

```
public class YourNewFilter extends MyGenericFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
                       final ServletResponse response,
                       FilterChain chain)
       throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException  { 
      ServletContext context= getServletContext();
      req.getRequestURL().toString() // use this method to get the end of the URL
      RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("https://appengineid.appspot.com/path/to/resource/" + end of the URL
     );
      rd.forward(request, response);

  } 
}
```

It is gonna intercept all requests in one domain and dispatch it to another.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response.

I don't think I explained my question fully so I don't think this is quite what I want. Question edited.